# XML to Object MULE duplicate nodes with same name

Tags: mule, nodes

I need to convert an xml to a java object in MULE.

```
<porto>
  <nome>example</nome>
  <nave>
     <x> a </x>
     <y> b </y>
  </nave>
  <nave>
     <x> c </x>
     <y> d </y>
  </nave>
</porto>
```

The problem I'm having is that I can't find a way with the "XML to Object" component to save the double "nave" component into the class.

I can't use Enterprise edition and can't change the xml. I can't use the JAXB approach either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem using the right annotation in the class:

```
@XStreamImplicit
private List<Nave> nave;
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because the transformation creates a Java map with nave as the key, and because the key is the same one of the nave elements overrides the other. You will need to write a custom transformer for that.

Using DataWeave it is possible to write a simple script to do the transformation but it is not available in the community version.

Example DataWeave

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
porto: { 
    nome: payload.porto.nome,
    nave: payload.porto.*nave
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatly I cannot use the Enterprise Edition that let you use DataWeave. I managed to do it using the annotation on the class variable like this:@XStreamImplicit
 private List<Nave> nave;